# Codeigniter not escaping single quotes in ODBC-mssql using ActiveRecord

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, odbc

I have a form with a bunch of fields. Sometimes users provides information and descriptions with single quotes in it.

I'm validating the data with Jquery and CI, the problem is that apparently ActiveRecord isn't escaping single quotes, leading to an error inserting/updating data.

Isn't ActiveRecord supposed to escape these characters automatically?  If it doesn't, what is the usual way for handing single quotes in user input?

Example code of my model function that handles the insert:

```
public function setLicense($dataArray, $data_id="")
{
    $iRows  = 0; // Rows found.
    $DB = $this->load->database('some_database',TRUE,TRUE);

    //var_dump($dataArray);
    if(empty($dataArray))
        return(FALSE);

    if(!empty($data_id))
    {
        $DB->where('idx',$data_id);
        $iRows=$DB->count_all_results('some_table');
    }
    else
    {
        if(isset($LicenseData['idx']))
        {
            $license = $LicenseData['idx'];
            $DB->where('idx',$license);
            $iRows=$DB->count_all_results('some_table');
        }
    }
    if(!$iRows)
        $DB->insert('some_table',$dataArray);
    else
    {   
        $DB->where('idx',$data_id);
        $DB->update('some_table',$dataArray);
    }
    return(TRUE);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like Javascript to me.  Your question basically boils down to "Shouldn't ActiveRecord handle this for me?" which can only be answered "yes" or "no."  See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints.

Comment: @RobertHarvey thats true a mistake re-tagged and changed title

Comment: I've edited your question to conform to the format that the Stack Overflow community generally expects when asking questions.

Comment: @RobertHarvey ok thank you for the edit ... learning ...

Comment: According to the documentation it does escape it on insert or update but it doesn't save it to the DB that way. So injection still shouldn't be an issue. Check here for more: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html The escaping queries part.

Comment: @RickCalder the problem is that the query is erronuos because the character is not scaping and closing string delimiters before it would

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the behaviour you're describing is intentional when connecting with the ODBC db driver.  Here is a quote from [this Ellislab forum discusssion](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/219401/#1012306):

> Due to the very nature of ODBC - you can use pretty much any database
>   platform without CodeIgniter having a way of knowing which one it is.
>   And different databases have different escape characters and rules, so
>   it’s really up to you to do such kind of escaping.