# xss filtering not removing single quotes in codeigniter

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, xss, sql-injection

i have been using codeigniter from some time i just now found an possibility of sql - injection in my script

When user enter

```
<script>alert('hi') </script>
```

in my input field `$this->security->xss_clean($field)` remove the scipts but it does not take care of single quotes of the string.
because of that i am getting query  error as

> Error Number: 37000
>
> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'hi'.
>
> SELECT * FROM account WHERE field1 = '[removed]alert('hi') [removed]' AND field2 = 'asdasd'
>
> Filename: D:\htdocs\system\database\DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 331

this is for typical xss string but when the user add `1' or '1'='1`

no error is being generated and query runs successfully .

i know this can be solved by `str_replace("'","",$field);`.

how can i solve this using codeigniter?

is there any global filter for this problem like (`$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;`)so that i don't have to add str_replace at all the input functions.

is there any way to generate log every time data has been clead with xss filtering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You try to protect yourself against SQL injection by calling `xss_clean`. `xss_clean` will protect you against xss injections, but will not prevent sql injections. Let me break it down to you:

SQL injection: Malicious user input, which tries to hack your database on server side. User input will contain SQL code.

XSS injection: Malicious user input, which tries to hack (spy in most cases) for other users. User input will contain Javascript code.

You need to protect yourself against both, but you should understand the difference.

Read [this](http://devzone.co.in/prevent-sql-injection-codeigniter-ci/) for SQL injection prevention in codeigniter. You can also use prepared statements, or [flourishlib](http://flourishlib.com/). As about protection against XSS, you can use `xss_clean`, or you can even write simple code in plain PHP:

```
public static function protectArrayAgainstXSS(&$arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $index => $a) {
        if (is_array($a)) {
            App::protectArrayAgainstXSS($arr[$index]);
        } else if ($a !== null) {
            $arr[$index] = strip_tags($a);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As a developer you want to know what is going on as far as user input, **don't** run any xss filters on user input, allow them post whatever they want, it will get stored as a string anyway, which can't harm your server. this gives you the ability to see what users are trying to do(attempt code injection), make sure you store an IP.  Yes IP's are dynamic, but the range is not. So if you see 2/3 attacks from the same IP range, you might want to block the range, then in your view(output) you would run the xss filter. so no code gets injected

Comment: this solve my confusion ... i think i was looking for sql injection prevention and focusing on the xss insted .  thanks ...

Comment: @Philip, this depends on strategy. Notice that I did not specify the location, where protection against XSS should be imminent. This depends on the strategy of development. As about tracking the IPs: Believe me that if I intend to attack your site (I am not that kind of guy, but let us imagine the case for a minute), then I will use proxy servers. Also, if I am attacking your site from a public network, then you will prevent other users from accessing your site as well. Let's not add this discussion to the technical debate of SQL and XSS injection.

Comment: @VikramSangat, if you find my answer useful, you can accept it

Answer (score 0):

xss_clean is not good function for using in SQL query at all! XSS and SQL injection are two separated domains. From your description it is something like [strip_tags](http://php.net/strip_tags) and this is totally useless function for protecting before SQL injection.

https://ellislab.com/codeIgniter/user-guide/database/queries.html

You have to use escape* function or query parameters binding for sanitizing SQL queries. I do not use codeigniter but these concepts are general. Solution with str_replace is not also really good path.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id = ? AND status = ? AND author = ?"; 
$this->db->query($sql, array(3, 'live', 'Rick')); // All three values should be escaped properly
```

Comment: good post in pointing out the difference! fyi - what codeigniter calls active record - escapes the queries.

Comment: @kbarborak thanks this works perfectly... i have only one question .. does your solution is same as `$where =array('field1'=>$field1,'field2'=>$field1);
$this->db->select('*')->from('table')->where($where);
$query = $this->db->get();`

Comment: when using active records i got to know this problem .. where active records are not taking care of  " ' " single quotes at all.

Comment: Interesting because [in docs](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) they tell us `All values passed to this function are escaped automatically, producing safer queries.` for `$this->db->where()` function. But I found one more thing for you - [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13054094/codeigniter-not-escaping-single-quotes-in-odbc-mssql-using-activerecord). It could be general problem with ODBC and CodeIgniter ActiveRecord. If you are on windows try sqlsrv extension instead odbc.

Answer (score 0):

if you are on CI 2, make sure you are using most recent version of codeigniter (2.2.1) it had some xss clean & other security improvements.

in terms of the issue you are having updating the database -- just use CI active record. if you use codeigniter active record for the database actions, then codeigniter automatically escapes the queries.

also suggest to take a look at the docs for CI 3, there's more recent info about xss clean and the security class.